# Plants vs Zombies Avoda Zara

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, christianity, games-toys

In the digital game Plants vs. Zombies, there are graveyard tombs in the shapes of crosses. Does this constitute avoda zara? Is it therefore assur to play this game?

Comment: See also a more severe form of this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28057/2

Comment: And possibly related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26742/128

Answer (score 8):

I would assume that there's no issue, as these crosses were only made for a design (in the game) and would fall under the heter of Shulchan Aruch YD 141:1, where he permits any figure presumed to have been made for merely aesthetic purposes. Even though the crosses on the gravestones are meant to be religious symbols, these particular crosses aren't worshipped and are merely symbolic, just like 'figures hung on the neck' (i.e. crosses worn as necklaces), which the Rama (there) says is not an idol and therefore permitted to be looked at.

Comment: Expanding on this, it's the game that's setting up these particular crosses. So if there were any *avodah zarah* taking place, Dr Zomboss would be committing it, not the player. So put the crosses under *herem* and plant Grave Munchers on those gravestones.